# What to call $R/\langle [R,R]\rangle$? The “commutation”?

Tags: ring-theory

Given a non-commutative ring $R$, is there a name for the quotient ring $R/\langle[R,R]\rangle$ of $R$ by the commutator ideal? Inspired by the name *Abelianization* of the group-theoretic analogue to this construction, it would seem natural to call it the “commutation” or something similar (“commutativization” being a bit too hard to swallow). But is there a standard name for it?

Comment: Commutativization would be the most natural, and "commutation" just doesn't make linguistic sense to me. But a better underlying question still remains: why do we need a fancy word for it? Looks like authors seem to get along without picking a name for the quotient.